# Creating a Tentacle Ball in Blender 2.8/2.9

Tags: modeling, physics

I saw this video on creating this Tentacle Ball in Houdini. https://vimeo.com/248824842

I am wondering what would be the most efficient way to create this in Blender. I am fairly new but trying to understand how to approach such a task. I have googlged for similar things in Blender on youtube but it didn't yield any good matches

I was thinking a few ideas, not attached to any.

1. Modeling the Tentacle Ball from scratch then attaching Rigid body physics to it.

or

2. Using Hair Particles with Ball

Again. I am not attached to any one idea, just looking for an efficient way to achieve this.  Since most of the time, I pursue and research a method only to find a better and more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach with the *Hair Particle System*:

[image: example animation of 2 hairballs]

I made it mainly because I wondered if you can render the animation in Eevee and how long it will take to render a short animation. The problem is that the emission requires a baked light probe and it's static, not dynamic.

The **modelling** is quite simple:

- create a sphere. Remember its face count (as shown stastic text overlay and status bar). It's 386 in this example.
- apply the *Scale* to the object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode if you have scaled it. The settings in this example are for default cube size (not scaled).

Enough modeled. Now the **hair settings**:

- add a *Hair Particle System* to the sphere object
- adjust the *Emission* settings:

  - *Emission > Number* set this to the *`face count`* of your sphere object
  - *... > Hair Length* and *... > Segments* as you desire. Less segments makes the tentacles stiffer, more makes it more tentacle-ish. Try `1 m` to `4 m` and `5` to `10` segments.
  - set *... > Source > Emit From* to `Faces` (default) and *... > ... > Particles/Face* to `1`
- enable `[X]` *Hair Dynamics*. The *... > Structure > Stiffness* value here also can be used to make the hair stiffer.
- *Cache*: if you have more than one ball give the cache a unique name. Double-click or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click the first nameless entry in the list
- *Render > Path > Steps*: increase the number to `4` or `5`
- *Viewport Display > Strand Steps*: use the same number as for the *Render* above
- *Children*: `None` if you want to have fat tentacles like the little ball on the screenshots -or- `Simple` if you like hairy ones like the big ball on the screenshots.
- if you want hairy tentacles and used `Simple` then

  - try `20` for *Children > Display Amount* and *... > Render Amount* and
  - a *... > Radius* of `0.3 m` (depends on the size of your sphere)
  - increase the the *... > Clumping > Clump* value to something near 1 like `0.950`
  - use *... > Clumping > Twist* if you like (`0.557`, screenshot #3)
  - experiment with the *Children > Roughness* settings if you like the hair strands rough and a bit messed up
- the *Hair Shape* section is important

  - set *... > Strand Shape* to a negative value like `-0.5` to have a thicker strand. It affects the thickness along the root to the tip.
  - set *... > Diamenter Scale* to `0.3` for fat tentacles (no children) or `0.05' for hairy ones
- last but not least, you can play around with the *Gravity*. Decrease it if the tentacles bend downwards to much (kinda like stiffness).

**Render Settings**

- set ***Eevee*** *> Hair > Hair Shape Type* to `Strip`. This way you see in the viewport what you get when you use Cycles.
- for fat tentacles set ***Cycles*** *> Hair > Shape* to `3D Curves`

**The shader** is simple. It's the *Hair Info* node and a *Color Ramp* node. With two *Math* nodes you can rotate the color ramp for a pulsing effect. With the *Hue Saturation Value* node the colors can be changed, and you can mix them. A *Noise* texture for the *Emission Strength* gives an interesting effect.

[image: shader]

For the glowing I've used two *Glare* nodes (Ghosts, low, 2 it. & Streaks, high, 3 it.) in the *Compositor*. In Eevee it's a bit darker compared to Cycles. But it works, looks not that bad and is a lot faster (~15sec vs ~2min).

Cycles render:
[image: cycles render]

Eevee render:
[image: eevee render]
The settings for the right ball were changed a bit. Both have a *Point* light in the middle now, and *Material Settings > Settings > Shadow Mode* is set to `None`. For the lights *Custom Distance* is activated and set to `3 m`.

This is to fake the light in Eevee. It's ok as long as there are no noticable reflections in the environment.

Comment: Spot on. This is great! I will try this method! Can there be two right answers?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try it with *Cloth* simulation? *Soft Body* seems much heavier to calculate.

I've weight painted the body (not the tentacles) in order to create a group to pin in the *Cloth > Shape* panel. In the same panel, set a high *Quality Steps* value. Play with the *Stiffness* parameters: low *Compression* value and high *Bending* value. Maybe tweak the *Internal Springs* parameters as well? Then animate with some keyframes.

[image]

Comment: This is great. How were you able to model it so quickly? Did you select every other face and extrude? 

Sorry, newbie here.

Comment: yes, I've created a cube, right click > subdivided it (then smoothed in the Operator box on the bottom left of your 3D view), inset the faces with double i, Alt E to extrude along faces, then extruded again, chosen Pivot Point > Individual Origins and scaled, etc

Comment: I got the model. I will play with the Cloth simulation to get it to animate correctly. 

Thanks! Case closed.

Comment: @moonboots Nice tentacle ball! How would you UV unwrap it to texture it?

Comment: I guess it depends on what kind of texture I would put  ;)  If I texture paint, a simple Smart UV Project?